# Does Jeremiah 33 predict that when the messiah comes Judah will live in peace and prosperity?

Tags: prophecy, eschatology, jeremiah, messiah

> ESV Jeremiah 33: 14“Behold, the days are coming, declares the LORD,
>   when I will fulfill the promise I made to the house of Israel and the
>   house of Judah. 15**In those days and at that time I will cause a
>   righteous Branch to spring up for David**, and he shall execute
>   justice and righteousness in the land. 16**In those days Judah will be
>   saved, and Jerusalem will dwell securely.** And this is the name by
>   which it will be called: ‘The LORD is our righteousness.’
>
> The ESV® Bible (The Holy Bible, English Standard Version®) is adapted
>   from the Revised Standard Version of the Bible, copyright Division of
>   Christian Education of the National Council of the Churches of Christ
>   in the U.S.A. All rights reserved.

Is the prophetic "in those days" referring to the imminent battle with the Chaldeans? Is the prophetic "in those days" referring to the arrival of the messiah? It sounds like they are to be the same days.

Either way it appears that the prophecy was not fulfilled.

Or is it referring to a more distant future?

Comment: It’s reference to any events in the future are off topic here as this calls for speculation from modern religious traditions. That part of the question should be asked on [Christianity.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the messiah is related. In this chapter Jeremiah still locked in the middle of the city חצר המטרה while the remaining people suffer from the siege.
So he locked there and than god speak with him about comfort that will come to Judeah, with the renew of buildings and land. Where peace will be kept, and the house of david will lead. 
This prophet did come true with Zrubavel returns after Koresh declaration.

Comment: What part do you see the "righteous branch" playing in the prophesy?

Comment: I think it display the relation between the house of david (the original kings of Judeah) as the natural leaders of the people. Isaiah use this metaphor more than Jeremiah, maybe because the disapoitment that Jeremiah felt.

Comment: So not necessarily the messiah. So would this have been fulfilled in the defeat of the Chaldeans in Jeremiah's own day?

Comment: As i wrote, i think it fulfilled during the Zrubavel return to Zion. It also refer to the prophacy on chapter 31 and it is described in the books of Nehemia and Ezra. Remember that most of the prophacies of Jeremiah did happened in those 70 years. Relating this to messiah miss the big picture that connect the books in one piece. But on the other hand, if one won't see connection to the past - how people will know that he real.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question here ~ this passage refers to a time peace and safety for the inhabitants of Judah and that obviously was not the case in Jesus day - it has not yet been fulfilled!   And the lineage/descendants of David shave been scattered across the globe.........very interesting indeed.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  This does not appear to answer the question because it is not an answer but a comment.  Are you able to add something here that answers the question?

Answer (score -1):

"In those days Judah will be saved, and Jerusalem will dwell securely" has a contemporary application due to current world difficulties. The Jews were commanded to ever wander and have no peace until they settle within the world community or kingdoms of the earth. Jerusalem is currently a place of contention and strife. For Jerusalem to dwell in peace the violation of the covenant has to be reconciled.

Freedom to their own people must be declared as that means the declaration of freedom to all the 'kingdoms of the earth'. The freedom from slavery to their materiality and financial power is meant according to Jeremiah. The current news media is a window to the agony of the middle east. This the messiah awaits. JPC.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. So are you saying that it refers to a future event?

Comment: Yes, this has yet to be achieved and is, therefore, referring to a future event.

Comment: This answer, as it stands, merely expresses an opinion. It requires considerable substantiation.